# How to read PMML in java and create a network visual?

Tags: java

Is there any way to read PMML file and create a network visual from root node to leaf nood using java and vis?
 In my application, I want to upload a PMML. I except this [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZFgj.png).

Advance thanks.

Comment: see if it helps: https://github.com/jpmml

Comment: thanks @wleao, I have already seen it before but because there is no proper document. I can't understand.